# Why isn't $U = \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} \mid \det(A) \neq 0 \}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm asked to see whether $U = \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}\mid \det(A) \neq 0 \} $ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$. I have no idea where to start though other than the subspace criterion which states that $U$ is a subspace of another vector space if two conditions are met:

- $U \neq \emptyset$
- for any $\lambda_1,\lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u, v \in U$, it holds that $\lambda_1u + \lambda_2v \in U$

Comment: Ah yes, I was confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not necessarily true that given matrices $A,B$, with $\det(A)\neq 0$ and $\det(B)\neq0$ that $\det(A+B)\neq 0$.

For example $\det(I_{3\times 3})=1\neq 0$ and $\det(-I_{3\times 3})=(-1)^3 =-1 \neq 0$ and $\det(I-I)=\det(0)=0$